# A quick question about the development of Laurent Series in Ahlfors

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading Ahlfors and I find myself completely stuck at one point of his development of Laurent series.
I'm perfectly happy with everything up until the line I highlighted at the bottom.

How do we know that $f_1(z)$ and $f_2(z)$ are analytic? What theorem are we using?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Lemma 3 from Chap. 4 Sec 2.3.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response!

Comment: I happen to be reading Ahlfors myself. :)